# Camel RabbitMQ publisher confirms

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

We need to know if the message from the producer has been delivered to the queue, not to the consumer. This is basically another way of checking if queue exists.

We are using Camel routing for our `RabbitMQ` messages and we need a publisher confirms. I know that `RabbitMQ` client provides publisher confirms but I'm wondering if Camel supports this feature. We are using Camel as follows.

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:event")
private ProducerTemplate producer;

void method() {
    producer.sendBodyAndHeaders("content", HashMapHeaders);
    //Confirm the acknowledgement 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Camel does support publisher confirms (see the [official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html)), you just have to enable them by setting `publisherAcknowledgements` property to `true` and optionally specifying a timeout interval through `publisherAcknowledgementsTimeout` property:

```
 to("rabbitmq://localhost/A?routingKey=B&publisherAcknowledgements=true&publisherAcknowledgementsTimeout=10000")
```

Please note that [support for this feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9399) is available as of Camel 2.17.0.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I think I will need a hook on my producer so that I can fail the transaction after timeout period. The test was not successful without the hook.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - if your route is transacted and no confirmation is received within the timeout period an exception will be thrown and the transaction will be rollbacked